# How to design and decorate class(es) so I can deserialize following xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I want to de-serialize following xml into custom class:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
 <title>test</title>
 <description>test</description>
 <language>nl</language>
 <link>http://www.test.test</link>
 <item>
  <link>http://www.testlink1</link>
  <pubDate>Di, 03 Nov 2015 09:08:44 +0100</pubDate>
  <sector>
   <entry>a:b</entry>
   <entry>a:c</entry>
   <entry>a:d</entry>
   <entry>a:b</entry>
  </sector>
  <title>test</title>
  <lead><![CDATA[test]]></lead>
  <description><![CDATA[test ]]></description>
  <images>
   <enclosure url="http://test.dll?tem=LTO_IMAGE_DOC&amp;size=1024&amp;doc_id=100782" length="608055" type="image/jpg"/>
  </images>
 </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Here is my class :

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("item", IsNullable = false)]
    public class CustomRssItem : BaseRssItem
    {
        [XmlElement("publisher", Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")]
        public string Author { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("guid", Namespace = "")]
        public string Guid { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("sector")]
        [XmlArrayItem("entry")]
        public List<string> Sector { get; set; }

    }
```

How do I modify my class to use custom class instead of `List<string>` so I can enclose parsing I need to do on entry element (splitting string against colon)?

Instead of `List<string>` Sector I want to write `List<GroupEntry>` Sector  where GroupEntry would be my custom class containing value "a:b" which I can parse and expose new properties like Group and Subgroup?

Comment: It's not at clear what you are asking. Please be more specific.

Comment: Create a `GroupEntry` class?

Comment: I did create GroupEntry class, but it doesn't get 'filled' ...

Comment: The xsd approach is the best practice I admit, but it will probably generate the GroupEntry type as string instead of a complex type because there is no way it to know what we try to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By implementing the GroupEntry class with correct XmlSerialization attributes, we can achieve that goal.

The class will have a and b fields, but you don't want these to be serialized, so we ignore them during serialization using the XmlIgnore attribute

Then we have an ab field, which we want to serialize as the element text. We make this happen by using the XmlText attribute.

We implement not only the getter but also the setter for ab because this setter is the one XmlSerialization will call when you are deserializing an instance of this type from xml.

Here is the required GroupEntry class code:

```
public class GroupEntry
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public string a;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public string b;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText]
    public string ab
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}:{1}", a, b);
        }
        set
        {
            a = null;
            b = null;
            if (value != null)
            {
                string[] split = value.Split(':');
                a = split[0];
                if (split.Length > 1)
                {
                    b = split[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would suggest

1. Create XSD from XML file [image: XML to XSD]
2. From XSD [Create Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) for it [image: XSD to CS]

And below is the generated Class, now based on this class you can adjust your class or use the below class as is. You can also rename the properties and customize all the names by decorating them with appropriate attributes.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.81.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class rss {

    private rssChannel channelField;

    private decimal versionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public rssChannel channel {
        get {
            return this.channelField;
        }
        set {
            this.channelField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal version {
        get {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class rssChannel {

    private string titleField;

    private string descriptionField;

    private string languageField;

    private string linkField;

    private rssChannelItem itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string title {
        get {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string description {
        get {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string language {
        get {
            return this.languageField;
        }
        set {
            this.languageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string link {
        get {
            return this.linkField;
        }
        set {
            this.linkField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public rssChannelItem item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class rssChannelItem {

    private string linkField;

    private string pubDateField;

    private string[] sectorField;

    private string titleField;

    private string leadField;

    private string descriptionField;

    private rssChannelItemImages imagesField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string link {
        get {
            return this.linkField;
        }
        set {
            this.linkField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string pubDate {
        get {
            return this.pubDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.pubDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("entry", IsNullable=false)]
    public string[] sector {
        get {
            return this.sectorField;
        }
        set {
            this.sectorField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string title {
        get {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string lead {
        get {
            return this.leadField;
        }
        set {
            this.leadField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string description {
        get {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public rssChannelItemImages images {
        get {
            return this.imagesField;
        }
        set {
            this.imagesField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class rssChannelItemImages {

    private rssChannelItemImagesEnclosure enclosureField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public rssChannelItemImagesEnclosure enclosure {
        get {
            return this.enclosureField;
        }
        set {
            this.enclosureField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class rssChannelItemImagesEnclosure {

    private string urlField;

    private uint lengthField;

    private string typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string url {
        get {
            return this.urlField;
        }
        set {
            this.urlField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public uint length {
        get {
            return this.lengthField;
        }
        set {
            this.lengthField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type {
        get {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```